# C++ Pointers and Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am taking a C++ class in school and was give a few lines of code with errors and I'm having trouble finding all 4 errors. The code is supposed to print the number "302"  I'm not good with pointers.
Here is the code

```
int main () {
int* ptr;
int* temp;
int x;
ptr = int;
*ptr = 3;
cout << ptr << endl;
x=0;
temp = x;
cout<<*temp<< endl;
ptr = int;
*ptr = 2;
cout<<*ptr-*temp <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The two errors i have found so far are

1. cout and endl need to have ::std in front of them
2. temp = x needs to be a pointer, *temp = x

Comment: `ptr = int;` won't compile; the author probably intended `ptr = new int;`

Comment: Also `*temp = x;` will invoke undefined behavior unless `temp` was already pointing to a valid `int` (which in this example it is not); perhaps you wanted `temp = &x;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers already pointed out the problems, their explanation and a possible solution, except for problem in this:

> 2. temp = x needs to be a pointer, *temp = x

No, you are wrong here. Pointer `temp` is uninitialised and dereferencing an uninitialised pointer (`*temp`) will lead to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Two ways you can solve it:

**First**, allocate memory to `temp`

```
temp = new int;
```

and then you can do this

```
*temp = x;
```

In this, the memory allocated to `temp` will have an independent copy of value of `x`. Make any changes to value of `x` does not reflect in the content of memory pointed by `temp` pointer and vice versa. Make sure to deallocate the storage allocated to `temp`, once you done with it because the memory it is pointing to is allocated dynamically.

**Second**, assign address of `x` to `temp` pointer

```
temp = &x;
```

`temp` pointer is pointing to `x`. Make any changes to the value of `x` and `*temp` will give the current value of `x` and vice versa. No need to deallocate the `temp` because the memory it is pointing to is not allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Include `<iostream>` to sort out `cout`, `endl` errors. Typically C++ compiler needs to know from where these functions are coming.

```
#include <iostream>
```

use `std::cout` and `std::endl` instead of just `cout` and `endl`.

`new` operator was missed in `ptr` and `temp` pointers

```
ptr = new int;
temp = new int;
```

Note, as you are dynamically allocating memory for `ptr` and `temp`, ensure it is removed via `delete ptr`, `delete temp` after its usage.

Comment: Don't recommend [using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) globally.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sure, will add a note.

Answer (score 0):

For less line of code i prefer using namespace std globally, this will resolve the problem of using std::cout everytime

```
using namespace std;
```

other than that you will have to allocate memory to the pointer after declaring it which can be done by using the new operator(don't forget to deallocate the memory after ur work is done using the delete operator), so instead of `ptr = int;` use

```
ptr = new int;
```

also using `temp = x;` is wrong as u are assigning the address of pointer temp to a varible value, using `temp = &x;` should be the right approach